# Run all Python bdd Behave and unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, python-unittest, python-behave

I have a python application with a number of unit tests which I implemented using unittest library.

There are also a number of bdd tests which I implemented using Behave package.

Is there a way to run all of the unit tests along with the bdd tests from one python file and fail as soon as any of the tests fail?

Comment: A simple shell script with both commands and a conditional exit? Any continuous integration system?

Comment: In a python file please

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you invoke the unit tests, but you could add a behave feature file that would implement steps to run the unit tests.  This could just be a another feature within the behave framework, e.g., "all unit tests pass" and you could have a scenario like:

```
Scenario: All unit tests pass
Given the application is ready to test
When I run the unit tests
Then all unit tests have passed
```

And your unit tests will be executed as part of the behave invocation.